# Match text outside html tags without use look behind regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, safari, lookbehind

I have this expression to get the matched word outside an HTML tag like this, but it does not work in Safari.\ It gives me a negative look behind the error.

```
 const regex = new RegExp(`((?!<[^>]*)send(?<![^>]*<))`,'gi');  => /((?!<[^>]*)send(?<![^>]*<))/gi
```

There is an alternative to archive the same result?

Comment: In the linked solution, replace `<a .*?">` with `<[^<>]*>`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the suggestion, `<[^<>]*>` will work for complete words, but not for partials, Example: If I'm searching for `send` but `sending` exist, I would like to get `sending` and but replace the `send` with for example `<mark></mark>` basically I'm doing a `highlight`. How I can adapt the regex expression to cover this?

Comment: No idea what you mean, `<[^<>]*>` has nothing to do with matching `send` or `sending`.